# Create WAR using Maven and Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Maven and Jenkins. I need to replace property files and a certificate files being used by my web app before the build gets created.

The process should happen in the Jenkins work-space.I went through the docs and found out that this can be done using the pre-build steps. Any help or pointers to examples is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jenkins to run a couple of build steps in sequence by just adding multiple build steps. So you can create a shell script to perform the changes you want and put that as your first build step.

Be warned that you should setup you SCM checkout to `revert` your workspace if your build steps make changes to files under version control.